Setting Pod Name as cloudRoleInstance in Application Insights with OpenTelemetry in Python
I’m using OpenTelemetry to send logs from my Python application to Application Insights. The application is running in an AKS pod, and I want to set the pod name as the cloudRoleInstance in the telemetry data.
According to the documentation, this should be done automatically, but I’m seeing that the cloudRoleInstance is being set to a random UUID instead of my pod name.
Can anyone help me figure out how to properly set the pod name as cloudRoleInstance using OpenTelemetry in my Python application?
I’ve already tried configuring the pod name manually in the resource attributes, but I am unsure if it’s the right approach or if I missed a configuration step.

set the cloud role name as follows:
JSON
Copy
{
"role": {
"name": "my cloud role name"
}
}
You can also set the cloud role name by using the environment variable APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ROLE_NAME.

You can also set the cloud role name via environment variable or system property. See Configuring cloud role name for details.

To set the pod name as the cloudRoleInstance in your telemetry data for Application Insights, you can customize the resource attributes in OpenTelemetry by explicitly setting the cloudRoleInstance attribute.
Install the required dependencies:
pip install opentelemetry-sdk azure-monitor-opentelemetry  opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc

You can set the cloud role name using an environment variable or a system property. For more details, refer to Configuring cloud role name.
Below sample code is to send telemetry with the cloudRoleInstance set to the Kubernetes pod name

from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter
from opentelemetry import trace
import os

pod_name = os.getenv("HOSTNAME", "unknown-pod")
resource = Resource.create({
    "service.name": "my-service",        
    "service.instance.id": pod_name,     
    "cloud.roleInstance": pod_name,      
})
configure_azure_monitor(
    connection_string=os.getenv("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"),
    resource=resource
)
tracer_provider = TracerProvider(resource=resource)
trace.set_tracer_provider(tracer_provider)
exporter = OTLPSpanExporter()
span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(exporter)
tracer_provider.add_span_processor(span_processor)
tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
with tracer.start_as_current_span("example-span"):
    print("This is an example span being sent to Application Insights.")



union *
| where operation_Id == "9dc"



For additional information on using Container Insights for Azure Kubernetes workloads, check out this guide.
